# Grouping of Azure Table Storage in Server Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have noticed in the Server Explorer in visual studio for azure table storage that it automatically groups the "Metrics Tables". Is it possible to add this type of grouping for our own tables?